# itunes connect cant find registered user

Tags: ios, app-store

Im a newbie in iOS App Development. Recently I made an app for a client. And he registered for the Apple developer account and assigned me as an ADMIN. So i was able to create provisioning profiles, etc. But Once we got the app ready for distribution, i came to know that i dont have permissions to upload it to the app store. I thought of asking my client for temporary switch of his login password so that i can use it,(He doesnt have a Mac) but felt inappropriate and asked him if he can change my role to agent. Eventually he assigned me as an agent. But even after that when i try to distribute from XCode Organizer window it says, Cannot find a registered user with the username.

Can anyone say what am I doing wrong here?.. Or is it not possible for the second agent to upload to app store?!! Sorry for my bad English. Thank you guys. Your help is most needed. I have been googling around for a day and still couldnt figure it out. Meanwhile is it because that iTunesConnect is shut down till 28th December.

Comment: This discussion question related to binary uploads is appropriate at apple developer forums.

Comment: This seems to be off-topic as it is about **General hardware/software** voted to close. As for your issue have you been added as a user in iTunesConnect? Also Apple aren't allowing developers to submit there apps over the holiday period I believe this ends on the 27th December.

Comment: @SamBudda yes i do understand that. I saw similar question posted here earlier thats why i chose to post here. Sure i will post in developer forums too. Thanks.

Comment: @Popeye Is there any chance i can verify that apart from asking the one who transferred my role. Yes i can understand that iTunesConnect is down and i cant submit my app. But does the error message "username not found"  relates with that.

Comment: I would assume so since I am getting that error message when I try to submit an app, so don't worry about that. As for knowing whether you have access to iTunesConnect. An iTunesConnect account is automatically setup with every Apple Developer Account (Paid) this will be the admin one but it doesn't automatically add users that have been added to the http://developer.apple.com/ portal and it doesn't automatically add them the other way ever. So if the admin user hasn't added you, told you or even knows then I would assume you aren't authorized to use iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the holiday period Apple aren't allowing developers to submit apps to the review process - I believe this ends on the 28th December. So the iTunesConnect service is currently unavailable so you will not be able to submit through `xcode` or `Application Loader`

[image]

Apple gave developers plenty of notice about this by sending out emails to developers and associates in regards to this manner.